# How to queue build on the TFS build server (build controller) with shortest queue? How to configure load balancing on build controllers?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

We have two TFS build servers (build controllers) available for our application. Builds are triggered as configured in the build definition. Every build is configured via "Build Defaults" page to specific build controller.

Let's say we have a gated check-in build. Build time is 30 minutes, 3 check-ins are made per hour. Normally these 3 gated check-in builds are triggered on the build controller 1, other build controller2 is idle.

How to trigger gated check-in build on the build controller2 if build controller1 is in use?

Is it possible to queue build on the build server with shortest build queue? 
How to configure load balancing on build controllers?

EDIT:
I found possible solution for TFS2008 [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/LoadBalancing_TFS2008.aspx). I'm looking for solution working for TFS2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. A controller can balance a build out onto which ever agents are available and that match the agent pattern of the the build (as defined in the build definition). Unless you have a serious load of build's, I would stick with a single controller per collection and more agents.
The controller does very little work compared to and agent (which does the compilation, testing and deployment).

[image: TFS Topology]

For your cases I would try something like:

**Controller**

- Gated Agent 1 (on \\sv-BuildAgent1)
- Gated Agent 2 (on \\sv-BuildAgent2)
- QA Agent... (on \\sv-BuildAgent3)
- Other agents... (on \\wherever)
- ...etc...

Now each of the Gated Build's Definition you would set the Build Agent to "**Gated Agent ***" (It's under the **Process** tab in **3. Advanced** -> **Agent Settings** -> **Name Filter**.). This will now pick any agent that starts with "Gated Agent". You can easily scale this to as many agents on as many boxes as you need.

**EDIT:**

You can also put Tags on Build Agent to a achieve a similar result. This may be easier to configure. You Define the Tags in the Build Agent's properties and Configure Definitions to use them in the same section as the Name Filter (above).

Comment: I can see only build controllers on the "Build defaults" page. It is not possible to set the Build Agent to "Gated Agent *". Loadbalancer for TFS2008 is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/LoadBalancing_TFS2008.aspx)

Comment: You need to edit the Build Definition. It's under the "Process" tab in 3. Advanced -> Agent Settings -> Name Filter. (updating answer)

Comment: +1. This is good solution. But we have only one agent per controller :( Our builds are build in parallel (high CPU load), so for us the best solution is to use two separate servers with some load balancer.

Comment: I would remove one controller, but keep it's agents. - see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166.aspx

Comment: I've updated my answer again adding a bit more explanation as to why you don't need 2 controllers for one project.

Comment: I will try to configure our Controllers/Agents configuration to [this topology](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC292936.png). Thanks!

Comment: It's easy enough to do. Good Luck.